# setting class variable instead of working with redundant local variables in 'CreateView'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have created a view class inherit from

> django.views.generic.CreateView

All is working fine, but I have two times the following line of code in two different class methods:

```
event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

I have already tried to set a class variable in the **init** method, but all I have tried end up in error messages.

Here is my class with the redundant two lines:

```
class StaffCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Staff
    form_class = StaffForm

    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        """
        initial = super().get_initial()

        event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        initial['country'] = event.default_country_of_staff
        initial['max_number_of_shifts'] = event.default_max_number_of_shifts_per_staff

        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.event = event
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Can someone guide me how to do it the correct way?

Comment: What are the error messages you get? Please include them in your question.

Comment: whit the class definition I do not get any error. It is just the redundant code I don't like. I got errors when playing around with trying to set a class variable self.event in the __init__ method, which I have removed again.

Comment: Is event a ForeignKey from Staff to Event? If so, you should have event as a field on `StaffForm`, pass the event as the initial value for that field and then you do not need your form_valid method at all

Comment: yes, it is a ForeignKey in Staff to Event

Comment: You should pass it as the initial value on the form, the field can be made hidden so that the user cannot edit the value

Comment: So like this, I could get rid of the whole `from_valid` definition. Is this correct? Is there no way to have a `self.event` variable set by overriding the ` __init__` method?

Comment: Iain's comment is really not the right way to do things. There's no point sending things to the template (where they can be modified) and back, when it can all be done on the backend. But I'm not sure what the question is; if you want to assign to an instance attribute, what's stopping you?

Comment: my question is, where (which class method) should I use to set the instance attribute. I thought, the __init__ method should be the correct place, as this ist the very first method that is called when the object is instanced. But there, I run into different problems when calling `get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['pk']`. If I only have the two actual methods, I think the `get_initial` would be the right place, as this will be called before the `form_valid` method. But what if I have later on other methods, that are even called earlier. So it is more a question how to do it correctly.

Comment: by the way: when setting the attribute within `get_initial` PyCharm is warning me `instance attribute event defined outside __init__`. So I really think, __init__ should be the right place to do such things. But there it seams I do not have access by `get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the flowchart of `django.views.generic.base.View` in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View:

1. setup()
2. dispatch()
3. http_method_not_allowed()
4. options()

According the description of the `setup()` method, I think this is the place to set my instance attribute `self.event`

So my class looks like this now:

```
class StaffCreateView(CreateView):
model = Staff
form_class = StaffForm

def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
    self.event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])


def get_initial(self):
    """
    Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
    """
    initial = super().get_initial()

    initial['country'] = self.event.default_country_of_staff
    initial['max_number_of_shifts'] = self.event.default_max_number_of_shifts_per_staff

    return initial

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.event = self.event
    return super().form_valid(form)
```